# Component is not getting rendered using router-link in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Code snippet from Navigation.js

class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
          return (

```
    <Router>
 <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">

          <NavDropdown name="Test">
            <a className="dropdown-item" >

                <li><Link to={"/Invoice"} >Mexico Invoice</Link></li>

                   </a>
          </NavDropdown>

           <NavDropdown name="Analysis">
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="/Transaction">Audit Log</a>
        </NavDropdown>
      </ul>

   <Route exact path="/Invoice" component={Invoice}  />
             </div>
           </nav>
            </Router>
);
```

}
}

export default withRouter(Navigation)

I am rendering this component from App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div >
        <HeaderAmex className="App" />
        <div>
   <Navigation/>
   </div>
   <Route exact path="/invoice" component={Invoice} /> 
         </div>
         </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

export default withRouter(App)

Below is my Invoice.js

```
class Invoice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], isLoaded: false, transId: "" ,flag:true,errorFlag:false,show:false,displayContent:"",invoice:"",invoiceXmlBody:"",invoiceTransId:"",invoiceResultFlag:false,invoicedisplayFlag:false};

  }



  handleChangeInvoice(e) {
    console.log("inside handleChangeInvoice");
    let invoiceXml = e.target.value;
    if (invoiceXml !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ invoiceXmlBody: e.target.value });
    }
  }

  handleSubmitInvoiceXml =e=>{
   console.log("*******************inside handleSubmitInvoiceXml***************");
   let url = "xxxxxx";
   fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.invoiceXmlBody),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/xml"
    },
    credentials: "xxxxx"
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({
      invoiceTransId:json,

    });
    if(json===undefined){
this.state.invoiceResultFlag=true;
    }
    else{

      this.state.invoicedisplayFlag=true;
      console.log("inside=========else===="+this.state.invoicedisplayFlag);
    }
    }
 ) }


  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props
    console.log("---------------------------"+this.state.invoicedisplayFlag);
    return (

             <div className="App">
                <div>{location.pathname}</div>
        <br/>

          <label className="lable" style={{marginRight:19}}>
              InvoiceXml:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="invoiceXml" placeholder="Enter invoice xml" 
                onBlur={this.handleChangeInvoice.bind(this)}  style={{marginLeft:15}}
              />

            </label><br/><br/>


             <input type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmitInvoiceXml} name="Submit" value="Submit" className="submitButton"  style={{marginLeft:-60}}/>


            <br/>
            <br/><br/>



            <div  className={this.state.invoicedisplayFlag?"showDisplay":"hide"}>
            <h5>Transaction Id is :{this.state.invoiceTransId}</h5>



        </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Invoice)
```

and below is my index.js

```
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

 serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Can anyone please help me to display the invoice component.I am pretty new to React.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: i have added  <Route exact paths="/invoice" component={Invoice}   /> in Navigation.js component but getting below error:

Comment: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because `Navigation` component is outside the main Router and component path should be `path={''}` not `paths={''}`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

 class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }

 render() {
   return (
   <Router>
    <div >
        <HeaderAmex className="App" />
        <div>
           <Navigation/>
        </div>

        <Route exact path="/" render={()=><h1>main<h1 />} /> 

        <Route path="/invoice" component={Invoice} /> 
    </div>
   </Router>    
   );
 }
 }

export default App;
```

in order to access the location props in your component you have to warp Invoice component with `withRouter(Invoice)`

[How to pass the React Router location prop to a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203629/how-to-pass-the-react-router-location-prop-to-a-component/51203964#51203964)

Comment: Wraped the Invoice Component with withRouter(Invoice) but still getting the same error:"Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"                                                        Below are the changes that I have made:                                                                      render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props                                                        export default withRouter(Invoice)

Comment: Please edit your question and add Invoice component code I want to see the full code

Comment: Well, it looks ok! can you remove `location.pathname` line and check the props in render with `console.log(this.props)` and see if location still undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
   <div>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
     <Route path="/news" component={NewsFeed}/>
   </div>
</Router>
```

That is the example code of [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/). You use the Link component which uses the routes that you should have defined before.
I think you are also missing some setup. You should wrap your app inside the router.

I hope this helps you. But it seems that you did not understand react-router-dom. Reading the docs will help you.

Comment: I have updated the code as below but still I am facing error as:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"

Comment: added following router element: <Route exact paths="/invoice" component={Invoice}  />

Comment: Did you import a component called `Invoice` ?

Comment: Yes Invoice component is imported.